# Bypass XSS in script tag

Tags: xss, javascript, reflected-xss, self-xss

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.RPM = {"debug":false,"env":"user input"}
</script>
```

user input can be inputted with xss payload.

```
Filter is doing following replaces:
i)    " with \" 
ii)   \ with \\
iii)  / with \/
```

I have tried with:

```
window.RPM = {"debug":false,"env":"u</script><script>alert(1)<!--"}
```

Replaces to:

```
window.RPM = {"debug":false,"env":"u<\/script><script>alert(1)<!--"}
```

Above payload fails due to escaping of  `/` with `\/` i.e. `</script>` to `<\/script>`

Is there any other way around as `window.RPM` statement is already inside `<script>` tag so that we don't need to close the script tag and open it again.

Any other possibilities?

Comment: Are all of those replacements done in one go? Or do all the quote marks get replaced first, then all the backslashes, and then all the forward slashes?

Comment: Do order of replacements matter as replacements are done at server side. In server's response we get all those replaced.